# Issue with adding jar in OSGI bundle using <Embed-Dependency>

Tags: maven, osgi, esb

I'm trying to embed third party libs and application jar in a OSGI bundle.I read the felix maven plugin document and tried using **Embed-Dependency**. But it doesn't seem to have any effect. Here's my pom

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.test</groupId>
            <artifactId>taxonomymessagebundle</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.1</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <configuration>
                    <instructions>
                        <Export-Package>com.test.taxonomy.dao.*;version=1.0.0</Export-Package>
                        <Import-Package>*</Import-Package>
                    </instructions>
                    <Embed-Dependency>*;scope=compile|runtime</Embed-Dependency>
                    <Embed-Transitive>true</Embed-Transitive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

I'm **mvn clean install** to build the bundle. After the install, I took a look into the manifest file, it doesn't show any Bundle-Classpath or Embed information. Looks like it completely ignored the instruction. Also, the two dependent jars were not embedded as well in the bundle.

Here's the generated manifest:

```
code>
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Export-Package: com.test.taxonomy.dao;uses:="com.autodesk.taxonomy";version="1.0.0"
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0
Build-Jdk: 1.6.0_21
Built-By: bandops
Tool: Bnd-0.0.357
Bnd-LastModified: 1307492329392
Bundle-Name: Taxonomy Dao Bundle
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Created-By: Apache Maven Bundle Plugin
Import-Package: com.test.taxonomy.dao;version="1.0",com.autodesk.test.message
Bundle-SymbolicName: com.test.taxonomy.daobundle
```

Any pointers will be appreciated.

-Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `<Embed-Dependency>` and `<Embed-Transitive>` should both be inside the `<instructions>` tag.

Comment: .my bad, Thanks for pointing this out. Just a follow-up,once I run the mvn install, I'm getting an exception saying that I must provide an entry in <import-package> for all the dependent packages.Is this due to property <Embed-Transitive>true</Embed-Transitive> ? What is the best practice to deal with these kind of scenarios?

Comment: The `<Import-Package>*</Import-Package>` is not necessary, and that might cause the message you see. In general, I would be careful with embedding everything and the kitchen sink in your bundle using `<Embed-Transitive>`. There's probably another question on stackoverflow with advise for this scenario.